# call command line from python class

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a class which take a file, do some processes, and output a tab delimited file.
I need to sort this output file, the easiest way is command line: sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n

However, I would like to implement this into a python class.

I tried:

```
from subprocess import call

# classA take input file, do something, output a file, named 'tmp_output'
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self,tmp_input,tmp_output):
        self.tmp_input = tmp_input
        self.tmp_output = tmp_output
        self.dosomething(tmp_input)

    def dosomething(self,tmp_input):
        outputfile = open(self.tmp_output,'w')
        #dosomething
        # something = ...
        outputfile.write(something)

# call this class to do something
a=ClassA('tmp_input','tmp_output') # this output a file called tmp_output

# Another class to sort tmp_output
class Sort(object):
    def __init__(self,tmp_output,output):
        self.tmp_output = tmp_output
        self.output = output

    def sort(self):
        call('sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n self.tmp_output > self.output') # THIS STEP DOES NOT WORK
```

**My question** is how to call sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n, as the input and output are taken from class variables.

Comment: Why?  What is wrong with `sorted`?

Comment: I want to sort first with first column, then second with numeric sorting, then third with numeric sorting.

Comment: You can specify whatever sorting criteria you want to `sorted`, either via the `key` or `cmp` arguments.

Comment: You might wanna try, `call('sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n {} > {}'.format( self.tmp_output, self.output))`

Comment: Thanks, I trying with sorted.
`student_tuples = [
    ('john', 'A', 15),
    ('jane', 'B', 12),
    ('dave', 'B', 10),
]`


In [76]:`sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))`
Out[76]:[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
It seams does not use the second key. Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong. The second key is only used in the case of the first key being the same.